# Facebook comments plugin with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am trying to implement facebook comments plugin on a rails 4 App. I followed the instructions on the facebook comments [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/).

Added the scripts after the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1397110283902092";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Added the display div in my view:

```
<%= content_tag :div, '', :class => "fb-comments", "data-href" => request.original_url, "data-numposts" => "5", "data-colorscheme" => "light" %>
```

But the plugin isn't loading or being displayed locally or remotely, there is now error printed to the console.

How to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: have you specified app ID of your facebook app correctly

Comment: @Dave - Yes, its the correct app ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/YxmbL/) and let me know on this. It displays comments and i was able to post comment also.

```
.
```

Comment: Ah. It seems that my idiocy is without limits. It was blocked by an extension.