# Facebook Comment plugin doesn't show up on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

So i've been trying to add a FB comment plugin to a simple blog app and i've followed every step from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ 
but Nothing shows up on neither Development or Production. 
i'm wondering if it's because of other Java scripts blocking the code or what else could it possibly be. This question has been asked before but it wasn't really solved and i couldn't find any legitimate information on it. the person who asked the question said that he fixed it and was because " It was blocked by an extension". and no further explanations, i can't figure out what that means exactly. any answers would be appreciated.

Similar problem:
[Facebook comments plugin with rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185603/facebook-comments-plugin-with-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. it was a Kaspersky internet security extension on firefox on "Data collection block" mode